# Show that a subset is a submanifold of $ \mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, manifolds

Given the functions
$f_i : \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}, i = 1, 2, 3$ with

$f_1(x) = x_1x_3 - x_2^2$

$f_2(x) = x_2x_4 - x_3^2$

$f_3(x) = x_1x_4 - x_2x_3$

show that $M:= \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^4\setminus\{0\}: f_1(x) = f_2(x) = f_3(x) = 0  \}$ is a 2-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^4$

So I have to show that for all points $m \in M$ where is an open environment $U$ and two continuously differentiable function $g_1, g_2: U \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $M \cap U = \{x \in U : g_1(x) = g_2(x) = 0 \}$ and $ \operatorname{rank} \frac{\partial(g_1, g_2)}{\partial(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)} = 2 \; \forall x \in M \cap U$.

Obvious candidates for $g_1$ and $g_2$ are the $f_i$ ($i = 1,2,3$) which would have to be chosen depending on the $m \in M$. So firstly I'd have to find an environment for each $m$ where setting two of the three $f_i$ to zero implies that the third one is zero and then show the rank condition.

Any ideas?

Comment: What results do you have to allow you to conclude that a set $f^{-1}(0)$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, and that $M\cap N$ is a manifold if $M, N$ are "reasonably behaved" (e.g., transverse)?

Comment: None, I'm working through a textbook in which some equivalent conditions for submanifolds were discussed. The one that appears to be closest to the exercise above is:  $M$ is a $k$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ iff $\forall m \in M$ there exists an open neighborhood $U$  and $n-k$ continuously differentiable functions $f_j: U \to \mathbb{R}, j = 1 ,2 ,... , n-k$ such that $M \cap U = \{ x \in U: f_j(x) = 0, j = 1 , ..., n-k \}$ and $\operatorname{rank} \frac{\partial(f_1, ...., f_{n-k})}{\partial(x_1,..., x_n)} = n- k \; \forall x \in M \cap U $.